# node - how does async.map work?

Tags: node.js, async.js

After reading about `async`, I assumed the code below would output to the console the total of all values returned from the http/API call; but it seems to fire immediately after the first http call returns, and only shows a 'total' value equal to the first value returned from the API.

Where is my misunderstanding about how async.map works?

```
var http = require('https');
const
async = require('async');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dbUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

var total = 0;

var tokens = [ {
    name : "tron"
}, {
    name : 'cardano'
}, {
    name : 'nucleus-vision'
}, {
    name : 'ripple'
}, {
    name : 'litecoin'
}, {
    name : 'havven'
}];

function run() {

    doStuff();
    setInterval(doStuff, 1 * 60 * 1000);
};

function doStuff() {

    total = 0;

    async.map(tokens, httpGet, function (value){
          console.log('async done ', total);
        });

}

function httpGet(token, callback) {

    var url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' + token.name;
    http.get( url,
        function(res) {
            var body = '';

            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body);
                var price = parseFloat(jsonObj[0].price);

                total += price;

                MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    var dbo = db.db("crypto");
                    dbo.collection("tick").insertOne(jsonObj[0],
                            function(err, res) {
                                if (err)
                                    throw err;
                                db.close();

                            });
                });


                callback(price);
            });



        }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    });

};


run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callback` that is passed to an iteratee (`httpGet`) is used incorrectly. The first argument (`price`) is considered an error. From [the docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map):

> If `iteratee` passes an error to its callback, the main `callback` (for the map function) is immediately called with the error.

So

```
callback(price);
```

should rather be

```
callback(null, price);
```

So `async` does not halt after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two separate problems here:

1. As you may know, we cannot use `return` statements in asynchronous code like we would in synchronous code, which is why we use callbacks instead. Node-style callbacks are on the form `function (err, result) {}`, where the first parameter is the error (if any) and the second the result of the function (the return value). According to the [docs](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map),
   `Async.map(coll, iteratee, callback)` will stop the execution if the
   `iteratee` passes an error to its callback.

   As your `iteratee`-function is calling its callback as such: `callback(price)`, you're effectively stopping execution, as price is passed as the `error` parameter. What you want to do to "return" the `price` variable, is to call the callback as so: `callback(null, price)`
2. Typically, [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function))-functions are used for

   > appl[ying] a given function to each element of a list, returning a list of results in the same order.

   The map function of the async library does the same, IE: iterates through an array and returns an array of the resulting items, just like the normal map (below) method does.

   `[1, 2, 3].map(function (nbr) { return nbr*2 }) // returns [2, 4, 6]`

   The result parameter of your `callback` (IE, the third parameter to async.map) will be called with an array of prices, and not the summed value of the prices.

   `async.map(tokens, httpGet, function (error, total) {
       console.log(error); // prints undefined (unless there was an error)
       console.log(total); // prints an array of prices
   });`

For summing the values, I would recommend the [reduce](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#reduce) function, or simply sum the values returned as a result.